# When a `tf.data.TFRecordsDataset` has num_parallel_read=2 and draws from a tf.dataset it pulls 8 files before starting, not 2 as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm feeding tfrecord filenames to a `TFRecordDataset` from a generator dataset which handles obtaining and placing the tfrecords files locally as they are needed. The tfrecords files are large, and in total don't fit on the local filesystem. I'm placing them on a ram disk for speed of transfer, and therefore care about how many I have queued up at a time.

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=self.gen_tfrecords_files, output_types=tf.string, output_shapes=())
ds = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=ds, num_parallel_reads=2)
```

I was expecting the `TFRecordDataset` to sample 2 files at a time from my generator, however it's pulling 8 files from my generator before it ever starts training. I don't have any significant prefetching in the pipeline.

Can anyone explain why `TFRecordDataset` pulls so many more files than dictated by `num_parallel_read`?

`TF 1.14.0`